# How do I knock out only the correct sized knock-out with Carlon A238 ENT boxes?

Tags: electrical, junction-box

Carlon A238 plastic boxes have three ring knockouts for 1/2", 3/4", and 1" conduit fittings. When trying to knock out for 1/2", the 3/4" breaks out as well.

How do I prevent this, or if it's already happened, fix the now over-sized hole?

Comment: If you do accidentally knock out the wrong size hole you can use reducer bushings to fix it. Commonly referred to as "Chinese Money".

Answer (score 2):

[image]

They're not concentric so this might be easier than you think. I would take two flat-head screwdrivers to do this. Hold the box with one flat head against the back so that the head is supporting the 3/4" and 1" knockouts. Use the other flat head to pry the 1/2" out.

Comment: WILL TRY AND ADVISE.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the picture of the box Machavity posted you can see the slight indentations in the KO's that a small screwdriver will fit. Put your small screwdriver in the 1/2" KO indentation and strike the handle with your lineman's pliers (don't hit the lineman). This should break loose your selected KO.

You have to strike the selected KO where there is a connection to separate that connection and then break the other connection.

If you accidentally remove the ¾" instead you can use a pair of reducing washers to go back to ½".

These  are a little tricky but with practice you will figure it out.

Good luck and stay safe!

Comment: I DID EXACTLY AS YOU SUGGEST AND EACH TIME THE BREAKOUT TOOK OUT THE 1/2 AND 3/4. MY INSPECTOR WILL NOT ACCEPT METAL REDUCING WASHERS.

Comment: Hmmm yeah that is unfortunate. I don't like these types of boxes either and would opt for a box that only has ½" KOs if that is all you are using. Your inspector is ill-informed as reducing washers are identified for such use and there is no grounding or bonding to be accomplished with a plastic box anyway. Sorry you are having such bad luck with them. I would also contact the manufacturer and complain.  